# Disable created .lnk file when open a Microsoft office file

Tags: security, ms-office, lnk

When I opened a Microsoft Office file eg. Word, Excel,.. a ".lnk" file would be created automatic. This may pose security risk. And I found some CVEs which could attack thourgh ".lnk" file

Is anyway to disable or remove this process?